# Add checked cell in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried successfully to add all the cell number in a table. What I want to do is to add on the cell which will be checked (using a check box). 
I want to do it using JavaScript

/*here is the code*/

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<form name="addValue">
        <table id="countit" border="1px">
            <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice"/></td>
        <td>Some value</td>
        <td>Some value</td>
                <td class="count-me">12</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice"/></td>
        <td>Some value</td>
        <td>Some value</td>
                <td class="count-me">2</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice"/></td>
        <td>Some value</td>
        <td>Some value</td>
                <td class="count-me">17</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
            var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('td');

            var sum = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
                if(tds[i].className == 'count-me'){
                    sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }   
     document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>'; 
    }
           </script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery part  in your code?

Comment: he did mention he wanted to do it in Javascript, no jQuery.

Comment: @Jorrex the title suggests otherwise

Comment: Well, didn't see that. Lol. My bad.

Comment: I want it in Javascript

Comment: can you edit the html? using classes, id, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modifiying only the JS you can do something like that

```
 myFunction = function()
    {
            var tds = document.getElementsByName('choice');
            var values = document.getElementsByClassName('count-me');


            var sum = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
                if(tds[i].checked){
                  sum+= parseInt(values[i].innerHTML);
                }

                }

     document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>'; 
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/79yf5to4/

search by name instead of the element td. if you want to search by the element you have to search by the row and after by the td.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
function myFunction(){
var sum = 0;
$('#countit tr input[name=choice]:checked').each(i, elmt){
 sum += parseInt($(elmt).closest('tr').find('.count-me').text());
};

}
```

Comment: Well. The OP wants it in plain Javascript :/